# Why does Microsoft mention "not recommended" for procedure of configuring the SQL memory?

Tags: sql-server, memory

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/server-memory-server-configuration-options?view=sql-server-ver15#procedure-for-configuring-a-fixed-amount-of-memory-not-recommended

It reads: Procedure for configuring a fixed amount of memory (not recommended)

Why does it say procedure "not recommended"?

I want to upgrade the SQL server memory, so what is the recommended procedure?

Comment: I would probably open a [GitHub issue on the docs site](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues) to ask for clarification. It's unclear to me why it would have that annotation.

Comment: I believe the "not recommended" configuration is setting the min & max memory the same, to give SQL Server a fixed memory allocation. The last line of that section is "It is recommended to set a max server memory as [detailed above](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/server-memory-server-configuration-options?view=sql-server-ver15#max_server_memory)." which points to just configuring Max Server Memory

Comment: Ok I assumed it was about the procedure- specifically using the GUI to make this change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you specify the same for min and max ("fixed"), then there's no "wiggle-room" for SQL Server to adjust based on what happens in the machine. For instance, a job is starting and memory is required for that job.

Comment: Why does it assume I will set the same min and max value? The not recommended is for procedure from the looks of it.

Comment: Please read that section carefully. "Fixed" means setting min and max to the same value. At least that is how I read the text. Any other meaning is meaningless, since we always have a min and a max value (even if 0 and 2147483647 - those are values as well).

Comment: So suppose I set min as 0 and max as 100GB, min not equal to max. Is this becomes recommended?

Comment: Then you don't have it set to "fixed". Many of us prefer to specify a max server memory, I'm sure you will find plenty of articles out there on this topic. Even the setup program for SQL Server 2019 sets a max value!

Answer (score 0):

It isn't that specific procedure that is not recommended, it is manually setting the memory limits in general is not recommended.

There are circumstances where it *is* recommended¹² or otherwise useful³ but if you are just running one instance of SQL server and little else on the machine then you shouldn't play with these values and instead just let SQL Server and the OS deal with it. You could set them to something that is too low, you could upgrade the machine later and forget to increase the allocation, …

<sub>[1] for instance: some instances when you are running multiple things on the same server, one of which happens to be SQL Server</sub>
<sub>[2] for instance: some circumstances where you are running multiple instances of SQL Server on the same machine, as they don't cooperate to try share memory efficiently</sub>
<sub>[3] for instance: in a development/testing environment when you want to test performance in a more memory limited environment</sub>

Comment: A _lot_ of work has been put in to make SQL Server have reasonable default behaviors, and not require a bunch of DBA configuration to run well.  Because (and as a result of this) most SQL Servers run without the careful attention of an experienced DBA.